# Why I cannot use keyword argument on range function?

Tags: python

In the python documenation, it says:

> Any function argument, no matter non-optional or optional (with default value) can be called as keyword argument as long as one of the argument names matches. Keyword argument, however, must follow all positional arguments.

I tried this out:

```
kwargs = {'step':-1, 'start':10, 'stop':5}
list(range(**kwargs))
```

But python gives men an error:

```
TypeError: range() takes no keyword arguments
```

Why is this?

Comment: So whats the problem now? its very clear that `range() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: Where did you find that text? I cannot find *any reference* of it other than this post.

Comment: I have not been able to locate any text in the Python documentation, including the tutorial, that uses wording anywhere like what you quoted here. Can you please provide us with the source?

Comment: As you know by now the real answer is that `range` is a C function which for some reason does not have the same rules of python (would be nice to know why). 

People might hate me for suggesting this but I've being doing this for range since I have a terrible memory of what the order of things are. Imo this shouldn't be a problem so I'm fixing it: `range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`

Answer (score 26):

`range()` is not a *python* function. It is a C type; C types follow different rules for arguments and `range()` only accepts positional arguments.

See the [*Calls* expressions documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> **CPython implementation detail**: An implementation may provide built-in functions whose positional parameters do not have names, even if they are ‘named’ for the purpose of documentation, and which therefore cannot be supplied by keyword. In CPython, this is the case for functions implemented in C that use `PyArg_ParseTuple()` to parse their arguments.

The positional parameters of `range()` are not named so cannot be used as keyword arguments.

Comment: I liked your answer to the question this duplicates better :-P

Comment: @jedwards: not sure that that's a good duplicate target, however.

Answer (score 3):

As you know by now the real answer is that `range` is a C function which for some reason does not have the same rules of python (would be nice to know why).

But you can do this instead:

`range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`