# Why does range() not take keyword arguments?

Tags: python

When writing:

```
for i in range(0, 10, step=2):
    pass
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: range() does not take keyword arguments
```

Why does it not?

Comment: change it to for i in range(0, 10, 2):

Comment: I hope this answers you question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926657/6635464.